# Pagination order by date ignores some data having same date

Tags: sql, pagination, sql-order-by, keyset-pagination

I have multiple rows of data in an unsorted way (IDs are not showing any certain order). I want to display them ordered by date descending (`mdate` column). I use this query to load next page where the min date is extracted from the last row of displayed data (by JS).

```
select top 100 * 
from production 
where mdate < '2023/10/03' 
order by mdate desc
```

When I use `mdate < '2023/10/03'` obviously if there are any data remaining from 2023/10/03 which were not displayed before, will be ignored and if I use `mdate <= '2023/10/03'` some data may repeat.

How can I manage that?

Comment: https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results/fetch-next-page

Comment: Which dbms are you using? The above query is product specific.

Comment: Column mdate data type?

Answer (score 0):

Do not rely on mdate column only. Interact with ID column as well and complete your logic by a combination of mdate and ID:

```
select top 100 * from production where 
(mdate < '2023/10/03' 
  or 
     /* Remaining data from 2023/10/03 */
     (mdate='2023/10/03' 
     and
     /* sample ID to be extracted from last displayed data as well as did for max date */
     id<'21344') 
) 
order by mdate desc,id desc"
```

In the logic above, I added `id desc` for order also I tried to extract remaining data from  2023/10/03 by comparing against a max ID (21344 as an example extracted from previously displayed data) and combined those data with any other data having *mdate < '2023/10/03'*

Comment: Did you forget to change your account? How can we know the data and table that you didn't mention on your question?

Comment: No bro I didnt forget. Everyone can answer their own question if they found solution to contribute to developing the public knowledgebase @User12345

Comment: That where statement seems ugly. Why you need to hardcoded id there? How can you get that id where the date is different?

Comment: Ah, I see. Your answer seems really business-specific. Sorry if I misunderstood

Comment: So long as your `ORDER BY` contains enough expressions to uniquely determine the order of each row, you can just use `OFFSET ... FETCH` rather than having to manually compute the row offset and applying it via a specific `WHERE` clause.

Comment: I.e. if you still think `TOP` is the best way of doing paging, you've not paid attention to changes in the T-SQL language from over a decade ago.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever That's factually incorrect in this case. `OFFSET FETCH` by itself is *slower* not faster than using a `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` supported by an index on the same columns. See linked duplicate as well as https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset and https://blog.jooq.org/why-most-programmers-get-pagination-wrong/

Comment: You need to make sure you have a supporting index, either `(mdate asc, id asc) INCLUDE (OtherColumns)` or `(mdate desc, id desc) INCLUDE (OtherColumns)` to get an efficient query plan.